# Changing java.security.KeyStore password

Tags: java, keystore

Does anybody know how to change the password of a `java.security.KeyStore`? Here is how I created my `KeyStore`:

```java
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        if (keyStore.containsAlias(CERTIFICATE_ALIAS)) {
            keyStore.deleteEntry(CERTIFICATE_ALIAS);
        }

        keyStore.setKeyEntry(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS, privateKey, password, chain);

        keyStoreFileOutputStream = application.openFileOutput(KEY_STORE_FILE_NAME, Application.MODE_PRIVATE);
        keyStore.store(keyStoreFileOutputStream, password);
```

Comment: I don't really understand, why can't you just change the `keyStore.setKeyEntry(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS, privateKey, password, chain);` the `password char[] array`?

Comment: I don't understand either. You *have* changed it, by calling store() with a password. If you want to change it again, load it and store it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea I just need to store the KeyStore with the new password. I was looking for a "Change password" feature.